# Android 5.0 FAB Button for all API levels in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, api, button, floating-action-button

Is there any way to use the FAB button in older API's in Eclipse?
I could only find things for Android Studio.
Or is it possible to use them in Eclipse?
Or is it possible to only show up the FAB button on Lollipop devices?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use image button in your xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fab"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:textSize="28sp" />
```

then use a selector in your drawable for the background of the image button and to change color when pressed instead of ripple

res/drawable/fab.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:bottom="0dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#44000000" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#01bcd5" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:shape="oval" android:top="2dp">
        <solid android:color="#007787" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

this will work for pre lollipop